# Implement InApp Purchase in an existng project of Android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am working on a android project where I received an enhancement from client to add in App Purchase to add certain points in the game. So the player can increase his life by using in app purchase. I have checked the sample app provided by google and also configured inApp purchase same as it was doing. Now I want to do it from my live account so that live account can be used for testing and in live app.

Please provide links and steps by which I can get the details which I need to set in my application such as AppID etc.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add your email id to the testers account on google developer console.
- Add the iap products in google developer console.
- Sign the build with live keystore.
- Do inapp. (Make sure that the prompt that comes up says This is a test account bla bla)